# background-image in css is not working

Tags: html, css, image

What is wrong with the css code below:

```
body {
    background-image: #000 url(http://www.lifecaredirect.com/images/background-patterns/body-bg-36.jpg) repeat;
    color: #898989;
    font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, Verdana;
    font-weight: 400;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    font-size:13px;
    line-height:21px;
}
```

Have tried following variations also but still not working:

1. `background-image: #000 url("http://www.lifecaredirect.com/images/background-patterns/body-bg-36.jpg") repeat;`
2. `background-image: #000 url('http://www.lifecaredirect.com/images/background-patterns/body-bg-36.jpg') repeat;`
3. `background-image: url("http://www.lifecaredirect.com/images/background-patterns/body-bg-36.jpg") repeat;`
4. `background: url("http://www.lifecaredirect.com/images/background-patterns/body-bg-36.jpg") repeat;`
5. `background: url(http://www.lifecaredirect.com/images/background-patterns/body-bg-36.jpg) repeat;`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The `background-image` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-image) takes a single argument: the URL to the image.

You are confusing it with [the `background` shorthand property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background), which takes a list of values and applies them to various different full properties (including `background-image`, `background-color` and `background-repeat`).

Comment: Exactly, what I was going to answer, +1 for you.

Comment: Tried: background-image: url(http://www.lifecaredirect.com/images/background-patterns/body-bg-36.jpg); but still no success.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using background property you can use the color as well as the image together, but if you're using background-image property you can't use the color with the image, you're to use only the image, than for the color you're to use separate property, something as follows:

```
body {
    background-color: #000;
    background-image: url('http://www.lifecaredirect.com/images/background-patterns/body-bg-36.jpg');

}
```

or both the properties combined in single background property as follows

```
body {
    background: #000 url('http://www.lifecaredirect.com/images/background-patterns/body-bg-36.jpg');

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use only `background` property:

```
body {
background: #000 url(http://www.lifecaredirect.com/images/background-patterns/body-bg-36.jpg) repeat;
color: #898989;
font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, Verdana;
font-weight: 400;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
overflow-x: hidden;
font-size:13px;
line-height:21px;
}
```

[Jsfiddle - example](http://jsfiddle.net/dA53w/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove #000 and repeat :)

```
body {
background-image: url(http://www.lifecaredirect.com/images/background-patterns/body-bg-36.jpg);
color: #898989;
font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, Verdana;
font-weight: 400;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
overflow-x: hidden;
font-size:13px;
line-height:21px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qcr38/)

Comment: Tried the same but no success :(

Answer (score -1):

First you need to get rid of repeat. and add this after

```
background-repeat:repeat-y;
```

Then make sure that the url are in single quotes.

```
body {
background-image: #000 url('http://www.lifecaredirect.com/images/background-patterns/body-bg-36.jpg');
background-repeat:repeat-y;
color: #898989;
font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, Verdana;
font-weight: 400;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
overflow-x: hidden;
font-size:13px;
line-height:21px;
}
```